# DNS: How to find out which software a remote DNS server is running

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

### Situation

I know the IP address of a DNS server running in the same network on a machine which I can't maintain.

### Question

How can find out more about which software that DNS server uses?

Thanks for your help - if anythings unclear, please leave a comment.

Comment: you could use nmap but that can be dangerous.  There probably is an offical way to do this I just don't know it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many DNS servers are pre-configured with version information in DNS TXT records for the `version.bind` label in the *CHAOS* class. If this is the case with yours as well, you could retreive it by running

```
dig @dns.name.server version.bind chaos txt
```

Typical answers might include

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
version.bind.           0       CH      TXT     "9.8.1-P1"
```

or

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
version.bind.           1476526080 IN   TXT     "Microsoft DNS 6.1.7600 (1DB04228)"
```

or

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
version.bind.           0       CH      TXT     "dnsmasq-2.47"
```

Apart from this, tools for DNS fingerprinting exist, [fpdns](https://github.com/kirei/fpdns) probably being the most advanced one.

Comment: Just remember that many server administrators disable this feature if it's present.

Answer (score 3):

The DNS protocols don't have a discovery mechanism built into them like some other protocols do.

This leaves you with indirect methods, such as port-scanning and shoulder surfing, the use of which is not that advisable. If you need to know, working at the human layer is probably the most effective way to get the answer you want without being perceived as an attacker.

Comment: Or even if you *are* an attacker.